# `baseurl` when hosting fossil as CGI

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite, url, cgi, scm

I'm self-hosting a repository on https://example.com/, running Apache. I've created a CGI script named `index.cgi` under DOCUMENT_ROOT as described in https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/doc/trunk/www/server/any/cgi.md. So far navigating to https://example.com/index.cgi works as expected.

Now I want to remove that `index.cgi` part. I added an `.htaccess` with a single line:

```
FallbackResource /index.cgi
```

Now when I navigate to a URL like https://example.com/repo-name/timeline it also works as expected. However, all the URLs returned by fossil are of the invalid form https://example.com/index.cgirepo-name/timeline.

I tried adding a `baseurl` into the CGI, but it looks like that property isn't supported.

How do I make fossil cooperate?